# Literally BUILD my own Multidemensional Jagged Array

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this approach of creating an array, it seems still works :

```
Object [] a = new Object[5];        
Object [] b = new Object[5];
Object [] c = new Object[5];
Object [] d = new Object[6];
Object [] e = new Object[5];

a[1] = b;
a[2] = c;
b[1] = d;
d[1] = e;
a[1][2] = c; // error, how do I make this work if I insist of building my array like this?
```

What exactly I just did? Is this technically a multidimensional Array? Why can't I use for example a[1][2][2] to access the element, how can I access my data in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that obj[] is actually a reference value, so, I am looking to "bring the object out of that reference value", so I can use the array operator[] to access the value. For example, I declare a 1D array, like what I have in my original question, so I can use a[1].[2] to acess the value store in the array stored in a[1]

```
Object [] a= new Object[5]; 
Object [] b= new Object[5];
a[1] = b;
```

So maybe a[1] then something that bring the OBJECT out of reference value in a[1], which is b[], then use [2]  to bring out the value store at b[2].